# Unity - How do I increase a value while a key is held down?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
   public int power;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    player = GameObject.Find("Whyareyoulikethis");
    while (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        power = power + 10;
    }

    // Places the ball at the player's current position.
    transform.Translate(-player.transform.forward);
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        rb.AddForce(-player.transform.forward * power);
}
```

What this is meant to do is while the space key is held down, `power` will increase by 10. Unfortunately, this does absolutely nothing. When the ball is spawned, it simply just drops down with no force added whatsoever. I have also tried GetKeyUp and GetKeyDown as opposed to Getkey, but they made no difference to the final result. I have also tried this in an if statement under void Update(), but the same happened. As stupid as it was, I also tried it in its while statement under void Update() and crashed the engine as expected.

Answer (score 2):

That `while` loop blocks your game until it is done. So as soon as you enter it you will never come out since the `Input` is not updated inside of your while loop.

Also it makes no sense in [`Start`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Start.html) which is only called once when your GameObject is initialized and the space key won't be pressed there.

Move the check for [Input.GetKey](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetKey.html) it to [`Update`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Update.html) which is called every frame.

Than Cid's comment is correct and this will increase the power quite fast and frame dependent. You probably want to increase rather with a frame-independent 60/second so rather use [Time.deltaTime](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html)

in this case `power` should be a `float` instead

Than it depends where the rest should be executed but I guess e.g. at button up

```
public float power;

private void Start()
{
    player = GameObject.Find("Whyareyoulikethis");
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

private void Update()
{
    if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        power += 10 * Time.deltaTime;
    }

    if(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        // Places the ball at the player's current position
        transform.position = player.transform.position;
        // you don't want to translate it but set it to the players position here

        // rather than using addforce you seem to simply want to set a certain velocity
        // though I don't understand why you shoot backwards...
        rb.velocity = -player.transform.forward * power;
    }
}
```

---

Comment: I upvoted, but I strongly doesn't recommend to use this code as is. If your game runs at 60 FPS, `power` will be increased `60 * 10` times per seconds. If the games runs at 30 FPS, `30 * 10` which will provide differents result depending of the computer used. Consider using the time to provide your power increase. Take a look at [`Time.deltaTime`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html)

Comment: @Cid you're right .. expect `Time.deltaTime` is a property not a method ;)

Comment: Good catch Hugo, I haven't coded anything in Unity since 2 years :)

Comment: I'm likely still doing things wrong. I should mention that the reason transform.Translate(-player.transform.forward); is in Start() is because in update it affects the ball after it leaves the cannon.

I just tried your code and the result is still the same. For some reason, power += 10 * Time.deltaTime is underlined in red and causes compilation errors. I've also tried transform.Translate(-player.transform.forward); in both start and update and it didn't do anything.

Comment: `power` should be a `float`

Comment: Something else odd I've just noticed is that playing the AddForce in update results in no power, but placing it in Start() gives it whatever the value should be. If I replace power with 1000 in that line, it only drops down in update but it's thrown properly in Start(). Unity is really starting to mess with me.